# Understanding addition of angular momentum for six spin-1/2 nuclei in a molecule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, angular-momentum, wavefunction, symmetry

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.05929) Matthew Fisher proposes the use of so-called Posner molecules for quantum processing in the brain. I am trying to understand the arguments at the beginning of Section F (Section 6 in the published version [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0003491615003243)):

> Consider first the spin and rotational states of a single Posner molecule. Quantum chemistry calculations find a cubic arrangement for the calcium ions (eight at the cube corners and one at the cube center) but the phosphate ions on the six faces reduce the cubic symmetry to $S_6$, with one 3-fold symmetry axis along a cube diagonal (see Fig. 1)[22–24,16]. The quantum states of the six phosphorus spins can be labeled by the total spin $I_{\mathrm{tot}} = 0,1,2,3$, and by a "pseudo-spin", $\sigma = 0, \pm 1$, encoding the transformation properties under a 3-fold rotation, $\vert \sigma \rangle \rightarrow \omega^\sigma \vert \sigma \rangle$ with $\omega = e^{i2\pi/3}$. The quantum state with both spin and rotations can be expressed as,
> $$\vert \Psi_\mathrm{Pos}\rangle = \sum_\sigma c_\sigma \vert \psi_\sigma\rangle \vert \sigma \rangle \tag{3}$$
> with the choice of normalization $\langle \sigma \vert \sigma \rangle = \langle \psi_\sigma \vert \psi_\sigma \rangle = 1$ and $\sum_\sigma \vert c_\sigma \vert^2 = 1$. The orbital wavefunction $\psi_\sigma(\varphi)$ depends on the angle $\varphi$ of rotation about the 3-fold symmetry axis. Fermi statistics requires $\vert \Psi_{\mathrm{Pos}} \rangle$ be invariant under a 120 degree rotation that interchanges the positions and spins of the phosphorus ions, [20] imply, $\psi_\sigma(\varphi + 2\pi/3) = \bar{\omega}^{\,\sigma} \psi_\sigma(\varphi)$ with $\bar{\omega} = \omega^*$. *The nuclear spin and rotational states are thus quantum entanglement in the Posner molecule*.

My understanding of the setup is the following: we have six spin-1/2 fermions arranged in an octahedron (at the face centers of a cube). Due to the presence of other atoms, the octahedral symmetry is reduced such that there is only a single $C_3$ rotational symmetry about a body diagonal (we could imagine "squishing the cube along the body diagonal" slightly so as to break the cubic symmetry). Here are my questions:

(1) Fisher says that the cubic symmetry is reduced to $S_6$. I do not think I am following his argument: $S_6$ is the permutation group of six elements, of order 64 ($2^6$). Cubic symmetry is the octahedral group $O_h$ of order 48. So I am not understanding where $S_6$ is coming from here.

<s>(2) I am having trouble with the total spin $I_{\mathrm{tot}}=0,1,2,3$. I understand we are adding six spin-1/2 angular momenta (with a total of $2^6$ states). I am used to adding angular momenta of two particles, but now I'm a bit lost with six. With the allowed values of $I_{\mathrm{tot}}$, it seems that there are only $\sum_{I=0}^3 (2I+1) = 16$ total states, not 64 which we have for 6 spin-1/2 particles.</s>

*The decomposition is not quite as simple as I thought for more than two angular momenta, it is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#Tensor_product_space), the proper decomposition is actually* **(7)** $\oplus$ 5 **(5)** $\oplus$ 9 **(3)** $\oplus$ 5 **(1)***, where the notation is (multiplicity)***(2s+1)**.

**Fundamental question:**

> [This is the biggest confusion I have and the main thing I would like answered]
>
> (3) I completely fail to grasp in what way $\sigma$ is a pseudo-spin, or what role it is playing in this decomposition. I assume this has something to do with irreps of the symmetry group for the $C_3$ axis (The $C_3$ rotation is represented by a unitary operator with eigenvalues $1, \exp(\pm i2\pi/3)$, the symmetry group is $S_3$.). It seems to me that $\sigma$ should be tied to the orbital angular momenta, since it is related to the eigenvalues of a rotation operator, yet the implication I get is that it is somehow related to the spin.

Answer (score 2):

Some values of $I$ will be repeated.  For instance, if you couple $3$ (rather than $6$) spin $1/2$ particles, the result is $I=1/2$ twice, and $I=3/2$ for $4+2+2=8$ states. If you want you can obtain the $6$-particle case by the repeated coupling of the $3$-particle case, *i.e.*
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1}{2}\oplus \frac{1}{2}\oplus \frac{3}{2}\right)\otimes 
\left(\frac{1}{2}\oplus \frac{1}{2}\oplus \frac{3}{2}\right)
\end{align}
and listing the outcomes of every distributed product in this sum.

Alternatively, if you are familiar with Young diagrams and Schur-Weyl duality, the resulting values of $I$ (and their multiplicities) are those associated with the partition of $n=6$ in at most $2$ parts.

Comment: Thanks, any insight about the pseudo-spin? That is the part I am most confused about