# 4 spin-1/2 particles representation

Tags: symmetry, quantum-spin, representation-theory

A follow-up question of $\frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2}=0⊕1 $ :
If I have 4 spin-1/2 particles in my system, how can I use a series of direct sums to represent  $\frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2}$ ? How to determine how many singlets, total spin 1 (I think that's 3), and total spin 2s are there? Thanks!

Comment: See the accepted answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35304/tensor-product-decomposition-of-su2) and extend it from three factors to four.

Comment: see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/571656/36194

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a general formula for the Kronecker multiplication of an [arbitrary number of doublets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#Tensor_product_space). Applied to your case, it yields
$$
\frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2}\otimes\frac{1}{2}= 2\oplus 1\oplus 1\oplus 1\oplus 0\oplus 0,
$$
a total of 16 states. These multiplicities are specified by
the [Catalan triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_triangle).

The general formula for *n* doublets is more transparent in a different notation to label your representations by their dimension *2s+1*, instead of the spin *s* that you use. That is, instead of your *s* =1/2, use **2**, instead of *s=0*, use **1**, etc.
$$
 \mathbf{2}^{\otimes n} = \bigoplus_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}~
    \left(\frac{n + 1 - 2k}{n + 1}{n + 1 \choose k}\right)~(\mathbf{n} + \mathbf{1} - \mathbf{2}\mathbf{k})~,
$$
where  $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ is the [integer floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions),  and the number preceding the
boldface irreducible representation dimensionality  label indicates multiplicity of that
representation in the representation reduction (the Clebsch series).

So, in your case, the formula reads
$$
\mathbf{2}^{\otimes 4} =  \mathbf{5}\oplus (3) \mathbf{3} +(2)\mathbf{1}, 
$$
displayed above. The advantage of this notation is   the arithmetical multiplicity of states check, automatically provided by taking away the boldface and circles, and providing a grade school arithmetic accounting of states!

Similar general formulas are available for arbitrary representation (spin) [additions](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physleta.2016.12.006).

Comment: @ Cosmas Zachos Thank you so much for the explanation! I'm wondering how many subspaces are there in this case? Are there 3 orthogonal subspaces (correspond to spin 0,1 and 2) of the total Hilbert space? Or are there 5 subspaces, each of which corresponds to a possible number of 'spin-up' particles (0,1,2,3,4)? Thanks!!

Comment: As indicated, there are 6 subspaces in the Clebsch reduction:, each corresponding to each representation. So, one for the spin 2 quintet,  three for the spin 1 triplets, and two for the spin singlets. Members for each representation transform among themselves completely ignorant of what happens to other subspaces.